# XMLRPC post working on curl call on linux command line but not in php curl?

Tags: php, http-post, xml-rpc, php-curl

I created a script for send the xml request using POST,It works perfectly on linux command line but not in php curl and this is my xml file and the command which I used.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>test.echo</methodName>
<params>
<param><value><string>nbb</string></value></param>
<param><value><string>health check: 1436777963</string></value></param>
</params></methodCall>

curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @test.xml -X POST http:my.host:5862 -v
```

This is my php script,

```
$url = 'http://my.host:5862';

#$requested = xml_gen($function_name,$epos,$time);
$requested = '<?xml version="1.0"?><methodCall><methodName>test.echo</methodName><params><param><value><string>nbb</string></value></param><param><value><string>health check: 1436777963</string></value></param></params></methodCall>';

#echo($requested);

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"ISO-8859-1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requested);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

echo $response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

//Decoding the response to be displayed
echo xmlrpc_decode($response);
```

This is the error I get with PHP's cURL.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 13 Jul 2015 15:26:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/XML
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, Have to add the user agent on curl request.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```